# Why this condition 0='=1' is true?

Tags: mysql

I have seen some programmers using this condition `0='"="1'` and don't know why it returns true ?Can anyone explain it to me ? Thank you!

Comment: Some programmers? Really?

Comment: It is indeed true. The question is... someone who actually uses this condition deserves a WAT? (https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to compare an number with a string the string is cast to a number.

When casting a string to a number, mysql accepts all leading numbers and throws away the rest. When there are no leading numbers, the string is cast to zero:

```
0 = 'abc' -- true: string cast to 0
1 = '1abc' -- true: string cast to 1
```

Your string is evaluated as being 0 because there are no leading numbers.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because yours is significantly better. Is it true that the RHS is always converted to the type of the LHS? Does `'' = 0` evaluate to true?

Comment: @Gray oops! your example was a good one: `'' = 0` is true, so I've changed my first sentence.

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks for checking. Couldn't that just mean that `0` is cast to `''` when it is a string? I wasn't trying to say you were incorrect, just wanting to understand how it chooses to cast. I thought there was some order of precedence, but you mentioned that it has to do with the side. I couldn't find anything that says you were wrong.

Comment: @Gray, `0` isn't cast to `''`. See [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: @MarcusAdams Thanks for the link. Very helpful in explaining how type casting works in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has no relation with "unusual" looks of the string. Yes. it's just primitive implicit type-conversion. You can do:

```
mysql> select 0='blablabla';
+---------------+
| 0='blablabla' |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

And see your reason:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'blablabla' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So same with your `'"="1'` - it's just string and will be truncated during conversion to `DOUBLE` causing zero-value.